# Material-UI/React: How to correctly add notification button with Badge to AppBar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui and react/jsx, I have an AppBar. I wanted to add a notifications menu icon with badge (number) on it, that is, to show the number of new notifications.

The problem is that the badge will be displayed incorrectly. That is, with weird styles and look.

Here is what I have already tried

```
<AppBar>
    <IconMenu anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
              targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
              iconButtonElement={
                  <FlatButton label={<Badge badgeContent={5} />} icon={<NotificationsIcon />} />
              }
    />
</AppBar>
```

That way, the badge will not be aligned correctly with the bell (notifications) icon.

I have also tried making the `IconMenu` part of the `AppBar's` iconElementRight property to no avail.

Any help?

Comment: could you please show it on webpackbin.com

Answer (score 2):

You're right - it does seem to take some experimenting with the proper nesting order, and even then you have to tweak the style a bit.  But, here's a sample webpackbin that I think looks decent without being hacky: http://www.webpackbin.com/EJqz0NVzM

```
<AppBar>
  <IconMenu
    iconButtonElement={
      <IconButton style={{ padding: 0 }}>
        <Badge
          badgeStyle={{ top: 12, right: 12, backgroundColor: colors.yellow800 }}
          badgeContent={5}
          secondary={true}
          >
          <NotificationIcon color={muiTheme.appBar.textColor} />
        </Badge>
      </IconButton>
    }
    >
    <MenuItem primaryText="View Notifications" />
    <MenuItem primaryText="Dismiss All" />
  </IconMenu>
</AppBar>
```

Once you nest the components correctly, the final bit is setting the padding on the IconButton to zero. Once you do this, it will look as expected according to the material-ui docs.

In this configuration, in my humble opinion, the badge is floating a little too far away from the notification icon. So, I also added a custom "badgeStyle" to nudge the badge inward to overlay on top of the notification icon slightly. I also put a custom yellow color on the badge too, just to illustrate that you can further customize the look of that badge (could change borderRadius, boxShadow, fontSize, etc)

Comment: webpackbin link is broken